# How to pull selected data from a table in a database

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I am looking to put the selected records contents into Labels after successfully allowing a user to login, however this is not working and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
Public dbName As String = "DB.accdb"
Public dbConnexStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & dbName
Public dbConnector As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(dbConnexStr)
Public SQL_Str As String
Public dbCommand As OleDbCommand
Public dbDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet("DataSetWJECComp")
Public dbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Public dbSource As BindingSource
Public dbCommandBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder

Private Sub BtnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnLogin.Click
    If LoginDetailsSearch() = True Then
        dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL_Str, dbConnector)
        dbDataAdapter.Fill(dbDataSet, "Selected Customer Details")
        Label5.Text = dbDataSet.Tables("Selected Customers Details").Rows(0).Item(0)
    Else
        MsgBox("The E-Mail address or password you entered is not valid, please check your entries and try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    End If
End Sub
Function LoginDetailsSearch() As Boolean
    dbConnector.Open()
    SQL_Str = "SELECT count(UserID) FROM Table_UserDetails WHERE EmailAddress ='" & txtEmail.Text & "' AND UserPassword = '" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
    Dim LoginCommand = New OleDbCommand(SQL_Str, dbConnector)
    Dim RecordFinder = LoginCommand.ExecuteScalar
    LoginDetailsSearch = (1 = CStr(RecordFinder))
    dbConnector.Close()

End Function
```

So it selects a record when you correctly enter a email and password which matches a record, however how do I pull the other fields of the record into labels? So the Name of the user into a label etc?

Comment: I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at Label5.Text = dbDataSet.Tables("Selected Customers Details").Rows(0).Item(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo have spelled your table name wrong: Selected Customer Details and Selected Customer**s** Details. I recommend you declare it as a string and substitute this variable name instead of typing it out twice.